# Formatting a reveal.js presentation with pandoc, how do I set .fragment on some list items

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js

I'm using Pandoc 2.17 to produce a reveal.js presentation.  I'd like to produce output like:

```html
<section>
<h2> Slide title>
<ul>
<li> This appears initially</li>
<li class="fragment">And this appears later.
</li<>
</ul>
</section>
```

Without the fragment I can get that easily with

```markdown
# Slide Title

- This appears initially.

- This appears later
```

I can use fenced divs

```markdown
::: {.fragment}

- This appears later

:::
```

Which will introduce an extra div (and break my unordered list into two lists) and apply .fragment to the div.
I can also insert the `li` element manually.
It looks like if I use the commonmark_x input format rather than pandoc flavored markdown I can do something like

```markdown
- This appears later.  {.fragment}
```

But reading  [this github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684) suggests there is some standard syntax for incremental slides:

> pandoc now includes a uniform syntax for transitions, which gets output as \pause in beamer and using fragment divs in revealjs. Of course, you can also just use a  in the markdown source, but this won't be portable if you decide to switch to beamer.
> I can't find that syntax though.
> I'd also like to learn if there's something like the commonmark attributes extension I can use in pandoc flavored markdown.

Answer (score 0):

So, I  have found the syntax for incremental slides:

```markdown
## Slide Title

- This appears initially.

::: incremental

- And this appears later.

:::
```

That introduces a secont bulleted list (the first bullet and the second are in different `<ul>` elements) and introduces paragraph elements around the text of the second bullet.
It also introduces an extra div.